# how to use Footable row-toggler for toggling the data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, footable

Guys I am really new to this ,please help me out.I am using footable for toggling the data.But i really don't know why is it not working.Well  tried the code as given in their documentation but still nothing works out.Help me out.
Here is what i am now-

```
<table class="table" data-toggle-column="last">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-breakpoints="xs">ID</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th data-breakpoints="xs">Job Title</th>
            <th data-breakpoints="xs sm">Started On</th>
            <th data-breakpoints="all" data-title="DOB">Date of Birth</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-expanded="true">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Dennise</td>
            <td>Fuhrman</td>
            <td>High School History Teacher</td>
            <td>November 8th 2011</td>
            <td>July 25th 1960</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Elodia</td>
            <td>Weisz</td>
            <td>Wallpaperer Helper</td>
            <td>October 15th 2010</td>
            <td>March 30th 1982</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Raeann</td>
            <td>Haner</td>
            <td>Internal Medicine Nurse Practitioner</td>
            <td>November 28th 2013</td>
            <td>February 26th 1966</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Junie</td>
            <td>Landa</td>
            <td>Offbearer</td>
            <td>October 31st 2010</td>
            <td>March 29th 1966</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>Solomon</td>
            <td>Bittinger</td>
            <td>Roller Skater</td>
            <td>December 29th 2011</td>
            <td>September 22nd 1964</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>Bar</td>
            <td>Lewis</td>
            <td>Clown</td>
            <td>November 12th 2012</td>
            <td>August 4th 1991</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>Usha</td>
            <td>Leak</td>
            <td>Ships Electronic Warfare Officer</td>
            <td>August 14th 2012</td>
            <td>November 20th 1979</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>Lorriane</td>
            <td>Cooke</td>
            <td>Technical Services Librarian</td>
            <td>September 21st 2010</td>
            <td>April 7th 1969</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is script-

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('.table').footable();
});
```

Here is the list of plugins i am using-

```
 <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.min.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/datepicker.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/footable.core.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/footable.standalone.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/footable.js"></script>
```

Let me know if i need to add any plugins other then the above.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: no ..it shows nothing @HiteshMisro

Answer (score 0):

I know i should not answer my own question but anyway i got the solution now ,so in case anyone needs it in future can have it right here. You only need to add two more plugins for this.Rest everything is correct.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/footable-demos.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/demos.js"></script>
```

They are present inside the demos folder in footable.
Anyway thanks.Let me know if this helps.It helped me.